# Is directly returning a modified function parameter a good practice in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to know if it is a good practice to directly return a modified function parameter in `Python`. Example:

```
def next_business_day_(day)
    while is_weekend(day):
        day = day + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return day
```

I often see functions written this way (see below), creating a separate variable to return. Is there any upside to do this? Other than the semantic meaning of the newly created variable name (i.e ret)?

```
def next_business_day(day)
    ret = day
    while is_weekend(ret):
        ret = ret + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return ret
```

Both function seem to work, but is there any downside using the first method? (i.e directly return the modified function parameter) which is more concise.

Comment: There isn't any unside or downside. Just in second function, there is a new variable so a lil bit of more memory would be used.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Python's function parameter evaluation strategy, which is not **by value** or **by reference**, but **by object**.

This **by object** evaluation strategy implies that you receive inside the function what you send when you make the call. If you pass a variable, you receive a variable but,

> if you pass immutable arguments like integers, strings or
>   tuples to a function, the passing acts like call-by-value. The object
>   reference is passed to the function parameters. They can't be changed
>   within the function, because they can't be changed at all, i.e. they
>   are immutable.

So, your first case would work as long as you (or whoever uses your function) passes a variable as parameter (`next_bussiness_day(day_var)`), but it would fail if he or she passes an immutable (`next_bussiness_day('sunday')`).

So, the best practice is the second one.

https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php